# И снова отправка HTML-формы на сервер

Tags: php, html, post, get, form

Есть обычная форма, которая отправляет данные методом POST (можно и GET) на ту же самую страницу, на которой находишься:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="something" value="">
  <input type="submit" name="press" value="send">
</form>

<?php if (isset($_POST['press'])) echo $_POST['something']; ?>
```

**ВОПРОС**
Эта форма находится на странице `site.com/catalog/?page=2` (то есть присутствует GET-параметр) и, когда происходит её отправка, то клиент оказывается на странице `site.com/catalog/` (исходный GET-параметр теряется).
Как сделать так, чтобы после отправки формы в URL-e сохранялся GET-параметр `?page=2`, т.е. чтобы клиент оказывался на странице вида `site.com/catalog/?page=2`.
Или хотя бы, чтобы форма автоматически отправляла "себя" вместе с тем GET-параметром.

**ПРОБЛЕМА**
Простой редирект `header('Location: site.com/catalog/?page=2'); exit;` после отправки формы не подходит, т.к. в этом случае:
во-первых, теряется информация, которая была отправлена формой (решаемо);
во-вторых, неизвестно какой именно GET-параметр будет введен.

Можно ли как-то решить проблему сохранения исходного GET-параметра в URL-e после отправки формы?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант можно проверить есть ли гет параметр и если есть, то передавать его в `action`.

```
<?php
  $url = (isset($_GET['page']) && abs(intval($_GET['page'])) > 0) ? '/catalog/?page='.abs(intval($_GET['page'])) : '/catalog/';
?>
<form action="<?=$url?>" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="something" value="">
  <input type="submit" name="press" value="send">
</form>
<?php if (isset($_POST['press'])) echo $_POST['something']; ?>
```

Comment: Спасибо! То что надо. Я бы повысил вам рейтинг, но у меня самого не хватает для этого репутации.

Comment: Еще несколько телодвижений на сайте сделайте и рейтинг появится. Не забудьте только ответ плюсануть потом :)

Answer (score 1):

Исправьте

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

на

```
<form action="?page=2" method="post">
```

Или если делать `get` то

```
<form action="" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="page" value=2>
```

Comment: Спасибо. А без скрытого поля никак нельзя передать GET?